# Values for the MVC Roles Authorize Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, authorization

I am learning MVC and while go through the concept of Authorization filters, I find that different hard-coded values are passed onto to the Roles attribute as shown below.

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    . . .
}
```

Also I have seen example with the roles values as "Admin", is there any predefined set of values to be used such and how this authentication internally takes places whether it takes the value from the environment variable / logged-in user , please advice.

Comment: [How Does System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute Work?](http://hellspawndev.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-does-systemwebmvcauthorizeattribute.html)

Comment: Hi Night, as per my understanding the snippet I shared ensures that users with admin permission are only allow to access the entire controller class methods that would be action results for the get requests from the browser